# place a gallery in the center of the page (html)

Tags: html, gallery

I'm making a webpage as a main hub for my class websites, and I'm putting the content in galleries. However, they automatically align to left, where I want them in the center, a few inches below the main title (a container).

```
.container1 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 75px;
    background-color: #FFF6A5;
    border: 5px solid #FFCF64;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 15px;
    top: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
div.gallery {
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 30px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 5px solid #FFCF64;
    background-color: #FFF6A5;
    float: left;
}
```

I know there's a "float: left" in there, but it's aligned to the left with or without it, it just makes it able to keep the galleries next to each other horizontally instead of vertically.

Here's what I'm putting in the galleries:

```
<div class="container1">
    <h1>Name // Field</h1>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
        <img src="images/headshot.jpg" width="300" height="400">
    </div>
<div class="gallery">
<h3>About me:</h3>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eu quo verear aliquid contentiones...
<h3>Websites:</h3>
<a href 
="http://website">Website Name</a><br><br>
<a href     
="http://website2">Website 2 Name</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to show the HTML.

Comment: is gallery inside container?

Comment: @connexo Fixed it.

Comment: @rahulmr No, it is not